# ubuntu 18.04 sssd not creating keytab file but works fine in 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, kerberos, sssd

Trying to bind a ubuntu 18.04 (because of compatibility issues with another app, need to use this specific version) I use a mod script:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt install -y realmd sssd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir adcli samba-common
realm leave
realm discover xxxx.local
realm join -U xxxx vgmtl.local
echo -e "[sssd]
domains = xxxx.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, pac
[domain/xxxx.local]
ad_domain = xxxx.local
krb5_realm = xxxx.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = False
use_fully_qualified_names = False
override_homedir = /home/xxxx/%u
enumerate = true
ad_enable_dns_sites = False
ad_enabled_domains = xxxx.local
ad_gpo_ignore_unreadable = True
" > /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
chown root:root /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
chmod 700 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/*
service sssd restart
```

When doing the realm join it gets stuck on:

Using GSS-SPNEGO for SAL bind

and just hangs there, the other thing I noticed, is that no xxxx.keytab seems created....

If running on ubuntu 20.04 --> runs perfect !?

Any help appreciated